# String object should be subscriptable but says int not subscriptable

Tags: python, int, typeerror

I keep getting this error, but I can't understand what I'm doing wrong.
I've looked at other similar questions and tried to apply them, but it didn't work.

The code is to chekc if the individual digits in a number, when ^3 equal to that original number.

```
def addCubes(a):
    total = 0
    for i in (0, len(str(a))):
        total += (a[i])**3
    if total == a:
        print("feck yah")
    else:
        print("NEIN!!!")
```

Comment: You mean `int(str(a)[i])`, not `a[i]`, as `a` is an integer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Convert `a` to string, then access the digit at index `i` of the string, convert the digit to `int`, then cube it:

```
total = 0
for i in range(0, len(str(a))):
    total += int(str(a)[i])**3
```

You could also try this:

```
for i in str(a):
        total += int(i) ** 3
```

Rewriting the function:

```
def addCubes(a):
    total = 0
    for i in str(a):
        total += int(i) ** 3
    if total == a:
        print("feck yah")
    else:
        print("NEIN!!!")

addCubes(371)

feck yah
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this in just `one-line`! Simply use a `generator` `expression` inside `sum` where you `cube` the `integer` value of each `character` in the `stringified` `a`:

```
sum(int(d)**3 for d in str(a)) == a
```

I will let you incorporate this into your `if-else` `statements`, but you can see it works:

When...

```
a = 28 --> False
a = 153 --> True
```